# Need to get application folder

Tags: c#

I need to get my application directory and add a file name to that path. So I used it this way.

```
String kofaxTextFilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(File)).CodeBase) + "\\KofaxBatchHistory.txt"
```

So it will give a path like this.

```
“file:\\C:\\Documents and Settings\\MyApplication\\ KofaxBatchHistory.txt”
```

But I need to get only

```
C:\\Documents and Settings\\MyApplication\\ KofaxBatchHistory.txt
```

With out doing any thing to this string is there any method to get it directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string myDir = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
myDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(myDir);
String kofaxTextFilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(myDir, "KofaxBatchHistory.txt");
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try `Assembly.Location`.**

```
Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(File)).Location
```

Or (better yet):

```
typeof(File).Assembly.Location
```

Answer (score 0):

See Environment.SpecialFolder enumeration, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx.

You might be looking for SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData